# Parent model still returns soft deleted child instance

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, soft-delete

I have a parent model `Library` which has many `Books`. Eloquent makes it so easy to define the relationships. I have enabled `softdeleting` on the book mode using the `SoftDeletes` trait.

#### Problem:

When I delete a book instance, the `deleted_at` attribute on the book instance is set to the current timestamp (as expected).

But when I query all the books that belong to the `Library`, the result contains all the books, including the ones that were deleted.

I only want to get the `books` that have not been deleted.

```
class Library extends Model {
   public function books() {
      return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
   }
}

class Book extends Model {
   use SoftDeletes;
   public function library() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Library::class, 'library_id');
   }
}

$softDeleteBook = Book::find(1);
$softDeleteBook->delete();
$books = Library::find(1)->books;
// $books contains even $softDeleteBook
// I do not want to get $softDeleteBook
```

Comment: after deleting does the `book` of id=1 deleted_at field in the DB changes to the timestamp or not ?

Answer (score 0):

@Elisha-Wigwe Chijioke. Have you added `$table->softDeletes();` to your migration file.

Sample model goes like this

```
<?php 
class Video extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('LearnCast\Category');
    }
 }
?>
```

Take a look at a sample migration schema build up

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You would need to add the `dates` as part of your model which is responsible for making the row you have deleted to be set to the current timestamp. By default, the deleted_at column would be `NULL` until you delete a record.

Comment: For futher reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting